# Migrating from MUI v4 to v5: Can't declare module "@mui/styles/defaultTheme"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm attempting to follow Material-U's instructions to migrate from MUI v4 to MUI v5, but ran into the troubleshooting issue Property "palette", "spacing" does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme.'

I'm following the troubleshooting suggestions listed [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#types-property-quot-palette-quot-quot-spacing-quot-does-not-exist-on-type-defaulttheme), and added the following code to my theme.tsx file:

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' {
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

but get the following error on the line `declare module "@mui/styles/defaultTheme` in `theme.tsx`:

```
Invalid module name in augmentation, module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' cannot be found.ts(2664)
module "@mui/styles/defaultTheme"
```

That code snippet does not throw the same error if I include it in App.tsx, but including it in App.tsx does not silence the `Property "palette","spacing" does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme` error.

How can I either a) avoid the invalid module name in augmentation error in `theme.tsx` or b) overcome the `does not exist on type DefaultTheme` error in a different way?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might not even need those lines. The module augmentation is only necessary if you are using `@mui/styles` together with `@mui/material`. Once you got rid of all the import statements of `@mui/styles` in your application, the error will appear. https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#%E2%9C%85-add-module-augmentation-for-defaulttheme-typescript